# Is it possible to declare a template class as a friend class without specifying the template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Here is a small code example :

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
     //
}

class B
{
    friend class A<..>
}
```

In this case, I want `A` to be declared as a friend class but without specifying the template parameters...

Comment: Why not simply write a very basic scenario and check it out? :)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. That one asks how to do it, and the answer is "by specifying the parameters", but this one asks how to do it without the specifying the parameters, and the answer is probably "you don't".

Comment: @rbaleksandar Writing a basic scenario without knowing the syntax is a long shot, that's what the question is for..

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: The answers there tell you how to declare a template as a friend. It doesn't specify the parameters, they're still "variable". Something like `friend class A<int>;` would "specify" the template parameters as far as I understand the question.

Comment: @Mat you are correct, it is indeed a duplicate, I just think the headline on the other question makes it hard to find (and this is why I couldn't find it myself)

Comment: @Mat, ah, I see. I thought that the question was how to do it without even using the `template` keyword. My bad.